# How to put a wordcloud in a pdf with a good quality

Tags: r, pdf, word-cloud

I am using the R package `wordcloud2`. It works fine, but I need to produce a pdf with the result and the only way I have found is the following.
I have already obtained a dataframe with words and corresponding frequencies:

```
> ds
          word freq
1         data   33
2        cloud   32
3  complessità   29
4       system   29
5      cliente   24
6       soglia   24
7      servizi   19
8      network   18
9     digitale   17
10       radio   17
11    progetto   15
12       scada   15
13   ticketing   15
14   telephone   14
15         web   14
16         app   13
17    business   13
18 engineering   13
19   requisiti   13
20     sistema   13
```

Now

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(webshot)
library("htmlwidgets")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
set.seed(142)
my_graph  = wordcloud2(ds, size = 1.5, #widgetsize = 10,
                       minRotation = -pi/4, maxRotation = -pi/4)
```

Once I have created the wordcloud2 object (note: I cannot find good values for `widgetsize`. Every time I use it, I obtain an empty image. Maybe I could use it to create an higher defined object), I put it in an html, and then i convert the html in a pdf:

```
# sizingPolicy(defaultWidth = 100, ....) <- possible solution?
saveWidget(my_graph, "myDocument.html"  , selfcontained = F)
webshot("myDocument.html","myFigure.pdf", delay =6, vwidth = 1500, vheight=1500)
```

I obtain a picture with a low definition:

[image]

In which part of the procedure can I set an higher dimension for my final image? I would like to take my `wordcloud2` graph (`my_graph`) and directly create a pdf (or png, etc.) with the dimensions I need. Is there a way?

Comment: You can use RStudio. Plot the figure and save per dropdown menu.

Comment: Ehi Jimbou, in that way I can save the figure with a very low quality. There's a limit on the allowed definition.

Comment: Try using larger `size` when creating the wordcloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You run your code

```
#Data
word<-c("data","cloud","complessità","system",
"cliente","soglia","servizi","network","digitale",
"radio","progetto","scada","ticketing","telephone",
"web","app","business","engineering","requisiti",
"sistema")
freq<-c(33,32,29,29,24,24,19,18,17,17,15,15,15,14,14,13,13,13,13,13)
ds<-as.data.frame(cbind(word, freq))
ds$freq<-as.numeric(ds$freq)

library(wordcloud2)
set.seed(142)
wordcloud2(ds, size = 1.5, #widgetsize = 10,
                       minRotation = -pi/4, maxRotation = -pi/4)
```

2) In RStudio You can open your worldcloud in google chrome

[image]

3) You save the output of google chrome in PDF (CTRL+P ->Save -> PDF)

[image]

4) Download your high quality pdf output here:
https://www.docdroid.net/3tZaVGm/capturar-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I've got better results setting the `selector` parameter of the *webshot* function to `'#canvas'`.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
webshot(
    url = "myDocument.html",
    file = "myFigure.pdf", 
    delay = 6, 
    vwidth = 1500, 
    vheight = 1500,
    selector = '#canvas'
)
```